# Deadlock error in Azure Analysis Services

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have just implemented Christian Wade's ["Automated Partition Management"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-as-automated-partition-management/) solution in my company.

But I got an error message when I run the process full of all tables.

I have this error message

> Exception message: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'The operation was canceled because a deadlock condition was detected with another transaction. This usually occurs when two transactions need to lock the same objects, but do so in a different order. Please retry your operation.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: The link didn't post quite right, but I found it with a quick google: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-as-automated-partition-management/